# ConTeXt: How to remove italics from book title in APA?

Tags: bibliographies, context

If I want to modify the existing style APA on the fly and remove italics from the book title, what is the best way?

This does nothing.

```
\definebtx[apa:list:title:book][apa:list:title][style=]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why `\definebtx` doesn't work for you, it does for me.  Anyway, you should be using `\setupbtx` instead of `\definebtx`.

```
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]
\usebtxdataset[default][samples.bib]
\definebtxrendering[default][apa]
\setupbtx
    [apa:list:title:book]
    [style=]

\starttext

\nocite[Tufte:1990:EI:78223]
\placelistofpublications[criterium=all]

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it helped!